# Routing in ASP.net core with Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a ASP.NET Core Web API with Angular project in VS 2019. I accepted all the default settings and it's successfully launched. My goal is to eventually create a combination of MVC, Angular with Areas and API in one project.

From the Configure method of Startup.cs, I can see the routing configuration is:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

and the SPA configuration is:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
     spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 80);
         spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
      }
 });
```

I would like to learn how the index.html (along with Angular content/components) under ClientApp/src is chosen to be sent to the browser as the default page. How does this work?

Comment: Do you have App.UseSpa(...) part at the bottom ?

Comment: @TodorPavlovic Yes. Do you know how that will decide the route behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every webrequest enters the HTTP request pipeline. This pipeline is constructed in the `Startup.Configure` method.
The web**request** traverses the pipeline from top to bottom, the web**response** traverses the pipeline back to the top.

The most basic, simplest middleware would look like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    // This middleware can manipulate the HTTP response headers,
    // response body, cookies, ...

    // We can decide if the next middleware should be called or not.
    // Sometimes this may not be necessary
    // (eg. serving a Sitemap, or a static file)
    await next();
});
```

In your case you have the following pipeline:

```
// This middleware reads the identity cookie and loads
// the information in the HttpContext.User. Finally calls the next middleware.
app.UseAuthentication();

// This middleware does something about routing decisions.
app.UseRouting();

// This middleware evaluates the AuthorizeAttribute to check if the route is accessible with the current Identity (which has been loaded before).
app.UseAuthorization();

// This middleware decides which controller method should be called. If a controller method matches the request url, the next middleware will not be called.
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

// If none of the above middleware has "handled" the request, or more precisely,
// If each of the above middleware has called the next() delegate,
// The webrequest will end up in this middleware.
// As far as I know, the UseSpa middleware will never call the next() middleware.
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 80);
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly  what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to access specific controller action method try with app.MapControllers();

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
 });
```

which will allow you call endpoint with attribute routing.

Comment: will probably do that. But still not clear about how current routing is working. I didn't post full code because don't know which part is related from a default Web API Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET 7 ASP .NET Core, try below.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
});
```

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/fallback-file-endpoints#recommended-action